# Minimal Spanning Tree of Distance Matrix (preferable numpy)

Tags: python, optimization, numpy, graph-theory, graph-tool

Lets assume we have a complete **directed** Graph and we want to calculate the Minimal Spanning tree by its Distance Matrix. Is there a efficient algorithm without involving packages from graphtheory? Might this be an application of neural networks?

Comment: Is there some particular reason why you can't use one of the [many](https://pythonhosted.org/python-igraph/igraph.Graph-class.html#spanning_tree) [existing](http://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/topology.html?highlight=minimum%20spanning#graph_tool.topology.min_spanning_tree) [implementations](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/development/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.mst.minimum_spanning_tree.html#networkx.algorithms.mst.minimum_spanning_tree) in various network analysis libraries?

Comment: Andreas Mueller has a pure numpy implementation of the Prim algorithm [here](http://peekaboo-vision.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/simplistic-minimum-spanning-tree-in.html), although it's probably not as quick as something like `graph-tool`.

Comment: Prim's algorithm only work for undirected graphs, I think.